# How to iterate through mysqli_fetch_all() method

Tags: php, mysql, sql

To my understanding
`$data = mysqli_fetch_all($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC)` will make `$data` associative array that contains associative arrays?

Let's say I have a table called users containing 3 columns: "id", "first_name" and "last_name"

`table users`

```
id--------|----first_name-----|-----last_name-----|  
1---------|----John-----------|-----Smith---------|  
2---------|----Jessica--------|-----Adison--------|  
3---------|----Brad-----------|-----Pitt----------|
```

now I fetch all the data using `$data = mysqli_fetch_all($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC)`

how do I itirate through each row and display id, first_name and last_name?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it in a `while` loop, getting one row of data at a time with `mysqli_fetch_assoc`:

```
while($data = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
    echo $data['id'];
    echo $data['first_name'];
    echo $data['last_Name'];
}
```

While looping (*see what I did there?*) you can add whatever markup you need or want to add.

If you want to use `mysqli_fetch_all()` it is a little different:

```
$data = mysqli_fetch_all($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
foreach($data AS $row) {
    echo $row['id'];
    echo $row['first_name'];
    echo $row['last_Name'];
}
```

Comment: but isn't this going to get me only the first row? Like `$row = $result->fetch_assoc();`

Comment: But `mysqli_fetch_all` __fetches all__.

Comment: I need to fetch all the data and pass that data to another class that have method to display data.  
do I iterate trough the data only with while ? or I need something like nested for cycles to iterate ?

Comment: You don't need anything nested, a simple `foreach()` will do.

Answer (score 3):

`mysqli_fetch_all` fetches all records from your query.

Result of `mysqli_fetch_all` is an array. You can iterate over it with a simple `foreach`:

```
$data = mysqli_fetch_all($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
foreach ($data as $item) {
    print_r($item);  // see what your item contains
}
```